# APC - PDU web-interface demo

Tags: power-distribution-unit

Where can i find a demo of the web-interface for Managed PDU's from APC (i'm interested in geting a glimpse at the features) ?

Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is appropriate here, but a quick google found:

http://testdrive.apc.com/pdu.htm

Comment: great. what did you googled for? :D

Comment: Would you believe "APC PDU demo"?

Comment: i got all fancy in "apc web-interface pdu demo" 10x a lot ;)